# VSO Copy Files Over SSH task - can it copy to my own on-premises linux box (raspberry pi)?

Tags: linux, ssh, azure-devops

Can the [Copy Files Over SSH task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh) copy to my own on-premises linux box (raspberry pi for my case)? I followed docs however am getting error:

`Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH endpoint details. Failed to connect to remote machine. Verify the SSH endpoint details. Error: Timed out while waiting for handshake..`

If not, what task supports this? Or how would I go about doing this? I see you can have your own local agent, or at least I think so, judging from this video: [Building and Deploy Applications In Linux With TFS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4-0onY8gmU) and maybe that's the kind of solution I need?

Been too long since I've played with VSO. But so far its been the least resistant path for most of my experimental projects. I'm open to other 'as a service' build/deploy systems, too though.

Answer (score 1):

Copy Files Over SSH task is supported for linux.

With Hosted agent, the target machine need to be accessible from internet, otherwise you need to setup a private agent (local agent)

The article about [deploying an agent on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/actions/agents/v2-linux)

Comment: I'd rather not set up an agent and instead make the target machine accessible from internet - or at least try this first. on my router I opened up port 22 on pi box and (confirmed it's reachable from outside world with  http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/) and can connect from my LAN however not from outside. I have ssh-rsa in the target's (pi box) ~/.ssh in an authorized_keys file. My Copy Files over SSH task is set up and configured to point to my dyndns hostname over port 22 with my pi box username and password as well as RSA private key uploaded. Am I at least on the right track?